# Log file in Solr

Tags: java, solr

guys, I try to use solrj in Java. At first I need to init a HttpSolrServer object.

When I run:

```
//This variable stores the default url of the solr sever
protected static final String DEFAULT_URL = "http://localhost:8083/solr";
//This is a static instance of solr sever.
protected static HttpSolrServer solrServer = null;
//This keeps the log
private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(SolrService.class);

//Create a solrServer instance. The connection time out is set to be 5000 ms.
static {
    solrServer = new HttpSolrServer(DEFAULT_URL);
    solrServer.setConnectionTimeout(5000);
}
```

It gives:

```
log4j:ERROR setFile(null,true) call failed.
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /logs/log (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:206)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:127)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.setFile(FileAppender.java:289)
at org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.activateOptions(FileAppender.java:163)
at org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender.activateOptions(DailyRollingFileAppender.java:215)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.activate(PropertySetter.java:256)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:132)
at org.apache.log4j.config.PropertySetter.setProperties(PropertySetter.java:96)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseAppender(PropertyConfigurator.java:654)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.parseCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:612)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.configureRootCategory(PropertyConfigurator.java:509)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:415)
at org.apache.log4j.PropertyConfigurator.doConfigure(PropertyConfigurator.java:441)
at org.apache.log4j.helpers.OptionConverter.selectAndConfigure(OptionConverter.java:470)
at org.apache.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:122)
at org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger(Logger.java:117)
at com.pressure.meta.search.SolrService.<clinit>(SolrService.java:23)
at com.pressure.test.search.SolrServiceTest.testBuildIndex(SolrServiceTest.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender [stdout].
```

Well I totally have no idea where the "logs/log" is. Could you help me with it please? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with Solr really, it is purely a Log4J configuration. You should be able to spot either a log4j.xml or log4j.properties file within your Solr directory (probably under the resource directory) which will allow you to update the appropriate location to save your log files. You can see examples on how to configure the XML and properties file on the [Log4jXmlFormat wiki page](http://wiki.apache.org/logging-log4j/Log4jXmlFormat).